# Dimentionality Reduction for Lp-Normed Spaces

Tags: high-dimensional-geometry, metric-spaces

Are there any dimensionality reduction techniques known for the general $\ell_{p}$-normed spaces for $p \geq 1$?

In the Euclidean space, there is a classical result: [Johnson-Lindenstrass lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) that can map any $n$ points to $O(\log n)$ dimensional space while preserving the pairwise distances up to a factor of  $(1+\epsilon)$ factor. From the lower bound perspective, the $\log n$ bound on the dimension is also tight (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02094.pdf)).

Are there similar upper or lower bound results known for the general $\ell_{p}$-normed spaces? Thanks.

Comment: Essentially no dimensionality reduction is possible in $\ell_1$: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6108191

Comment: You can look at the paper for some discussion on this topic. https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/5908/pdf/LIPIcs-SoCG-2016-16.pdf